# Post FLV to wall

Tags: post, flv, facebook-wall

If I use the Graph API to post something on a user's wall, the "source" attribute doesn't seem to work if the video source is an FLV.

What I expect is for Facebook to wrap their native video player around the FLV file, but it doesn't happen.

Here's how I'm calling the API: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K14dj.jpg

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can't include FLV content directly; you need to include your own SWF player, and attach the URL of the player you want displayed (passing the FLV source as a parameter in the SWF URL )

Comment: Like this: http://example.com/player.swf?URL=http://example.com/1.flv ? That seems to work, but the player loads in a new window when you click it in the post. Is there any way to make Facebook load the video player right below the post?

Comment: If the player is opening in a new window there's probably a protocol mismatch between the player source URL and the user's HTTP/HTTPS setting for Facebook - you can specify the HTTPS source separately

Answer (score 1):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Source: The URL of a media file (e.g., a SWF or video file) attached to this post. If both source and picture are specified, only source is used.