# Thumbnail of media file not being shown on wall post 

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post on user wall using garph api 'Feed method'. When i click on post dialogue appears to put some message that doesnot shows me the attached media file. And when i share , and check on wall there is no thumbnail

Following is my code snippet,

```
FB.ui({
               method : 'feed',
               to: '100001256527379',
               link : 'http://fbdbcalender.coeus-solutions.de/frontend/images/ecards/file-4faba9e79c380.flv',
               name    : 'I posted an eCard using Birthday Greetings',
               caption : 'Birthday Wish',
               description : 'Shared by Sarah',
               picture : 'http://fbdbcalender.coeus-solutions.de/frontend/images/covers/cover-4faba6056400c.jpg',
               source : 'http://fbdbcalender.coeus-solutions.de/frontend/images/ecards/file-4faba9e79c380.flv'


           }
           });
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567872/post-flv-to-wall) is an answer by a Facebook Developer - you simply can not do this with an FLV file... You'll need to provide a player within an SWF for it to work.

Comment: Thanks Lix for ur quick answer ... Can u tell me is it only for flv format or i have to provide player for all formats

Comment: If you want to "play" content on someones profile it'll have to be a supported video link such as youtube or vimeo.  If you want to play a custom **file** then you'll have to provide a player...

Comment: Thanks Lix .. thats so helpful